# Running MVC 5 app on VS 2015 gives different result then when running through IIS Express 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2015

I have a strange issue, as when I'm starting MVC 5 application on VS 2015 I get a different result then when starting the same app directly from IIS Express 10.

When I run the app from VS 2015 I get a **list of directories** or a **Bad Request - Invalid Hostname**, but when I start the app directly from opened IIS the it shows my app startup page.

That's the screenshot of my application Web tab in Properties:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL9j8.jpg

And here's the screenshot of the iis settings:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pz5q0.jpg

Please help!!!

I'm trying to deal with these from few days with no good result....

Comment: i believe there is something wrong with hosted site in iis express

Comment: I've tried many possible ways to fix it up, but nothing worked so far... Any idea what could be wrong? Many thanks!

Comment: can you show the screenshot of the application setting

Comment: What web server is used for your web project in VS2015? By default it should use IIS Express, and then your question itself is puzzling, as you cannot get different results when both are running on IIS Express.

Comment: I'm using IIS Express, and that's why I'm struggling... I cannot find the reason why the result is different...